# How to fast scrub a video or load a video in memory in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, avplayer

My final intention is to go to a video location and the preview should be available immediately.

Currently I am using `MPMoviePlayerController` to play the video and when I scrub through the video time bar there is some delay in the preview displayed. Though I have seen applications that show the preview instantaneously.

How is it possible? Are they loading the complete video in memory or are the using some different mechanisms using `AVPlayer`

Comment: Impossible to know what they are doing.  If you want to display a preview faster, you will probably need to drop down to a lower level like AVFoundation.  Loading the entire video into memory is not what you want to do.